# Use an ORDER BY with a query that already has GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm using MySQL and I have a table that has dates in a column (I'm making a table of due dates for a class). Previously I had the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM duedates_f2011 ORDER BY anothercolumn
```

In order to prevent duplicate occurrences (based on the duedate column) I had to change it as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM duedates_f2011 GROUP BY duedate
```

Currently, it's retained the same order, but how can I assure that it will still do so? Nothing in the `GROUP BY` tutorials I've read indicates that it will still sort it, and adding an `ORDER BY` statement afterwards is incorrect. Is there something I'm missing, or is there something else I should add to make sure it remains in order?

(as indicated in my tags, I'm using PHP to run the query)

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is what you want, but it may not be working because of other problems associated with the `GROUP BY`.  Can you show your statement with both clauses and indicate what columns are included in the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: Although the `GROUP BY` is sufficient (for MySQL) to guarantee and ordering, I think it is best practice to include the `ORDER BY` clause (it is allowed, and is clear documentation that you want the rows returned in a specific sequence. Note that MySQL differs from other database engines, which do NOT guarantee the ordering of a result set for a query absent an `ORDER BY` clause. (For example, we observe older versions of Oracle returning rows in GROUP BY order, but that was a side effect of the group by operation, not a guarantee. Later versions of Oracle don't return rows in GROUP BY order.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by ... order by ...` (in this order). If you use just `group by`, it will be ordered automatically by that column(s).

However, if you want to `group by duedate` and `order by anothercolumn`, realize one thing: the sql doesn't know which value to take for anothercolumn, when you group by duedate...

**edit**: from the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

> If you use GROUP BY, output rows are sorted according to the GROUP BY
>   columns as if you had an ORDER BY for the same columns.

Comment: I believe it is sufficient if it orders by the column I am grouping by. Thanks!

Comment: mysql does NOT accept *order by ... group by* and this automatical sorting of grouped columns is new to me (if it exists)

Comment: @guido It's `group by ... order by`.

Comment: @gms8994 that's exactly what i'm saying; another question now deleted was proposing the reverse order as well, i swear if that is valid in some other database (that i not aware of)

Comment: @guido: if it's new to you, [look in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), the `group by .. order by` has been fixed, thanks

Comment: @rar: yes, it is sufficient, see the note from the manual I've added to my answer!

Comment: +0 The behavior of MySQL (to output rows in GROUP BY order) is not consistent with other database engines. Even when it's not needed, I think including the `ORDER BY` clause is good documentation, and is consistent with the SQL required by other database engines to guarantee an ordered result set.

Comment: @spencer, what do you mean with "engines"? With engine you mean like PostgreSQL/MySQL/Oracle? Because the word "engine" has special meaning within mysql itself: like InnoDB or MyISAM.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM duedates_f2011 GROUP BY duedate ORDER BY anothercolumn;
```

This is according to the [MySQL manpages](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

Comment: This answer was downvoted, but it seemed to work :S Maybe it was for the reasons Tomas Telensky noted above. I decided to go with just simply the `GROUP BY` method. Thanks!

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. Best practice is to include the `ORDER BY` clause, even though it isn't required in MySQL, since MySQL guarantees the rows will be returned in `GROUP BY` order.  Other databases don't have this same guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting with a grouping first, then doing the order later, like this?

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM duedates_f2011 GROUP BY duedate) a
ORDER BY anothercolumn
```

I don't see any reason for you to settle on it being ordered by the grouped column. Be **bold**! Demand more of your database! It should bow to your every whim!

```
mysql> SELECT Jump FROM YourDatabase;
+----------------+ 
| Jump           |
+----------------+
| How high?      |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```